# Baked audio to fcurve>fcurve through a driver to animate a hook empty to deform geometry>works great... BUT

Tags: drivers, audio, fcurves

I've asked this question a couple of times in a couple of places and it's driving me crazy. I've baked drum beat to the x location fcurve channel of an icosphere so that it bumps to the positive x and back to 0 with every beat. Using a simple driver I am transferring that animation to a hook empty attached to a character's "butt" so that it bumps to positive x with the the same rhythm. What I want is the butt to swing with the rhythm (0 to x+1 then 0 to x-1 and so on like a sine wave). Obviously the audio wave form only goes from 0 to +1, so I need to figure out how to make every other drum beat drive the hook empty to the negative. There has to be a way to do it with the driver, but I don't know python. Help!

Comment: Blender does not "understand" music, it's also no audio editor so it cannot analyze the music to determine the bpm or the rhythm. So there are no indicators which beat should be +1 or -1 (it doesn't even know what is a "beat"). The only thing you could do is add a curve modifier with a sine wave to multiply the original curve with, and you have to manually adjust the size so that it fits the rhythm.

Comment: Yeah I know I'll have to "teach" it somehow. There is the one solution of isolating every other peak in the graph editor and mirroring them. I was hoping that the switch node could be tripped on the positive beat and keep track of the previous beat to always ×-1 if that makes sense. But I can't figure out how to keep track of whether the previous iteration was pos or neg... that way blender doesn't have to "understand" the beat, just whether the previous transform was positive or negative. But I can't figure out how to store that switch in real time as the animation is playing.

Comment: If you had a perfect waveform, you could use a GN object to keep track of its history, and "flip" every time the wave passed through an inflection point. Then you could control your hook from geo created by that object using constraints, in whatever fashion appropriate.  But, I don't see how you could possibly have a perfect waveform, so it's kind of moot.  If your waveform has any noise, then it has inflection points all over, and you don't want your animation to flip from that noise.

Comment: I thought about using a compare node to a switch node: if the value of the wave is > .01 then switch to (value *-1)) and then figure a way to record that switch as a true or false so that it could be refenced on the next pass. Maybe in the simulation zone? That effort just led to further flummoxing.